# Finding a GCF of any given number in C++

Tags: c++, math

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvBwv.png)

I do not have much knowledge in C++. I have an assignment to create a code to determine the GCF of any user input number. *See the attached pic*

Here is what I am thinking on how to tackle this. As shown in the flow chart. It makes sense to me. But I might be wrong. So please tell me if it makes sense.

One issue I have in the coding is that I can't get a way to write an array with it's "length" being dependent on how many factors of a particular number there are.

[image: flow chart]

### Edit

It seems to me as though people might have misinterpreted what my intent in my original post. I wanted help, not answers. I have written the code the the best of my ability (hopefully it shows my knowledge in C++, or lack thereof). Everything in // means it is code that I want to input, but I'm having trouble inputting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really weak question. Expect a beating unless you revise to show a bit more effort. The solution to an [array of unknown size is `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: When you have an array but don't know how big it should be then you want a `std::vector`

Comment: I don't know what "weak question" means. Should I show the code that I have?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe that my title was fairly detailed.

Comment: Recursion to solve it?

Comment: I dont know what recursion is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gcd

Comment: Can't find one that fits what I'm looking for. Just because I'm not good at C++ doesn't mean I don't know how to use the internet.

Comment: @MawalLamas, so what else besides `std::vector` you need to write some code? This site is not "solve my programming task for free". We are usually glad to help someone who has shown actual effort to solve issue himself/herself. Sidenote: as you can see from other answers about GCD on this side, noone in real life computes GCD by first factorizing number in prime divisors.

Comment: Why this is weak: It has the look of a zero-effort assignment dump. We don't know what you have done to attempt to solve the problem. I've made your image more easily visible, but the assignment spec... Well it's best to pick one problem and make a question about it. 4 tasks, 4 questions. Hopefully less because at the end of task one you should have a couple syntax questions by the time you hit task 2. Task 3, totally different beast, but take a look at prime sieving algorithms to make your life easier. Task 4, not a programming problem and shouldn't be here.

Comment: For a flow diagram you should [stick to convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) or odds are good the instructor will savage you. Open Office contains an opensource tool that can help you draw these up quickly.

Comment: I didn't expect for people to just do my homework for me. Did you guys look at the description? I clearly asked about the array. I used the prompt to show, why I might need an array / or I might not. Maybe there is a way to find GCF without using an array. If there is, I would like to know.                               Also, the flow chart (THAT I CREATED) describes that I need to have an array (if I need an array) that does not have a set amount of "slots".

Comment: Not sure if you guys have seen, but I edited the op.

Comment: Instead of working out array size in advance, you should use a resizeable container, e.g. `std::vector`.

Comment: The first image link seems to be down for me. Does it work for you OP, or anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> findFactors(int n){
    std::vector<int> factorVect;
    for (int i =0; i<=n;i++){
        if (n%i==0){
            factorVect.push_back(i);
        }

    }
    return factorVect;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout<<"Enter n";
    std::cin>>n;
    int m;
    std::cout<<"Enter m";
    std::cin>>m;
    std::vector<int> nfactors=findFactors(n);
    std::vector<int> mfactors=findFactors(m);
    std::vector<int> gcdfactors;
    int gcd=1;
    //get factor intersection of nfactors and mfactors, and store in gcdfactors
    for(int i=0;i<=gcdfactors.size();i++){
        gcd*=gcdfactors[i];
    }
    std::cout<<gcd;
    return 0;
}
```

You can figure out how to get intersection of the two sets on your own. I hope this helps!

Comment: wow! wow! wow! This was not my aim. I didn't want someone to just do it for me. I really appreciate it though. I don't want to sound ungrateful, but I also don't want to sound lazy.

Comment: Thats why I still left out one part!

Answer (score 0):

```
int gcd(int a, int b) 
{
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Comment: Recommend unrolling the `if` and using more descriptive variable names to make what you just did brutally obvious. Otherwise you have an unexplained phenomenon, and that just leads to [cargo cult programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Also remember that OP needs a list.